# Dolphin file manager hangs when opening a directory from the terminal

Tags: nixos, dolphin

Whenever I attempt to open a directory with dolphin (both with `dolphin /home/user` and `dolphin --select /home/user`) from a terminal it hangs, which seems very odd since opening dolphin without specifying a directory works fine (just `dolphin`). I suspect this is the reason why xdg-open and other applications file dialogs do not work. Any idea why specifically passing in a directory would break things? Distro I'm using at the moment is nixos

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, and quite frankly more of a hack than a solution imo, but it does seem to fix the issue with xdg-open and other applications file dialogs, which was the motivation for me posting this to begin with.

If you make a copy of the org.kde.dolphin.desktop file, place it within $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications, and edit `Exec=dolphin %u` to be `Exec=dolphin --new-window %u`, xdg-open appears to function properly (along with application file dialogs).

This still doesn't fix the underlying issue however, without that flag dolphin still hangs. Furthermore, upon more inspection from me attempting to solve the problem this wasn't the only argument that causes dolphin to hang. `--daemon` also appears to cause dolphin to hang as well.